# Rotate a curve to a point in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to rotate a curve to a pass through a point on a 2D plot but l cant find a way of doing it .
Say l want to rotate

```
y=np.exp(x)+2  #pass through (x=5,y=6) point
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract value of y(x_0) from y and add desired y.
For example

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.exp(x) + 2

x_ind = 5 #This is not value of x, this is index of desired x
y_desired = 6
y -= y[x[x_ind]] + y_desired

plt.plot(x, y, color='b')
plt.scatter([x[x_ind]], [y_desired], color='r')
plt.show()
```